# Integrate Paypal in multi merchant website

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a multi merchant website and in that what i need to do is when customer purchase a product 5% of the money is gone to website paypal account for service  and rest of the money will be gone to seller paypal account. I need to integrate paypal in that. As **paypal adaptive payments is deprecated** and paypal is not providing any other solution to do that.

Can anyone please tell me any paypal service which can make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need marketplace APIs. If you need PayPal APIs in specific, you can look into [PayPal for Marketplaces](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/#). Braintree (A PayPal service) has better APIs [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-marketplace).

[Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) is also a competitor with good reputation.

With all these APIs, you can control funds disbursement by specifying percentages as you mentioned in your post. I don't know what your complete use case is. So I'd suggest researching all 3 of these and choosing the one that best fits your budget and business model.

Comment: No, I did not. But I've looked into all these APIs a lot and understand all the terminology. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mathematical equation to give you the difference between
   the total and your 5% (or the seller's 95%).
2. Process the entire amount into your account.
3. Pay the seller their (95%) share by transferring that amount to their account.